# Replace all non NaN values with the initial value per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have the following dataframe:

```
Periods            0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7     8     9     10    11    12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
Item 1           89.0   89.0   88.0   86.0   73.0   73.0   67.0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Item 2          197.0  197.0  157.0  157.0  156.0  156.0  153.0  153.0   3.0   3.0   2.0   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
Item 3          105.0  105.0   98.0   47.0   40.0   21.0   20.0   15.0  13.0  11.0  11.0  11.0  10.0  7.0  7.0  5.0  5.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
```

It has several NaNs, and columns from a range between 0 - 20. What i wanted, is to replicate the first column to the next columns, until this value is not NaN. Let me show you an example of what it should look like:

```
Periods                0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19
Item 1               89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Item 2               197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Item 3               105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0
```

But I can't figure out a way to do this. I wish i could post some code, but all I tried was to search for those methods: backfill, ffill. None of them looked like what I needed.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you paste the result of applying the `.to_dict()` method to you dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am assuming here that "Periods" is the index*

You can use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) on the columns with `df.notna()` as mask, and the first column (`df.iloc[:, 0]`) as replacement values:

```
df.mask(df.notna(), df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0)
```

output:

```
             0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17     18     19
Periods                                                                                                                                            
Item 1    89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0   89.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Item 2   197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0  197.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
Item 3   105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0  105.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea, just for the record: using `map`:

```
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].notna().map({True: df.iloc[0, 0]})
```

Answer (score 1):

I will do `mul`

```
df.notna().mul(df.iloc[:,0],axis=0).mask(df.isna())
```

Comment: That's the first time i read about this method, called "mul". Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @bellotto it's just a function version of `*`. `df * 10` = `df.mul(10)`, `df + 10` = `df.add(10)` ;)